# How can I add URL parameters and remove characters using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL ending with `#/`, and I want to add the URL parameters that are selected in a select list to the URL and remove the `#/` from URL.

```js
$('#drop').on('change', function(e) {
  if (e.handled !== true) {
    e.handled = true;

    var url = 'https://www.geoplug.docksal/sales/rentals#/';
    // window.location.href = url + '?sort=' + this.value;
    console.log(url + '?sort=' + this.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="drop">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)?

Comment: Obviously the parameters part of your script works, so I assume that you're asking just about removing the two characters. That's been addressed many times before. See the links above.

Comment: FYI, you were missing quotes around your URL. Not sure whether that was tripping you up.